# Filter UITableView without the use of a SearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search, swift2

I'm trying to filter a UITableView without the need of involving a searchBar.

```
 func filterResultsBasedOnSideViewController() {

       print("filter value \(filterString)")

        filteredPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "keyWords contains[c] %@", filterString)
        filteredObjects = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.filter() {
            return self. filteredPredicate!.evaluateWithObject($0)
            } as! [myValues]?

        self.tableView.reloadData()


    }
```

But really nothing is happening when calling this. I am I completely wrong here?

And my fetchedResultsController is as follows for anyone who's wondering:

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
        if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
            return _fetchedResultsController!
        }

        let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        self.managedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("myValues", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
        fetchRequest.entity = entity

        // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sortID", ascending: true)

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
        // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
        let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

        do {
            try _fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
        } catch {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
             //print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
             abort()
        }

        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }    
    var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil

    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    }
```

Comment: try _fetchedResultsController = nil before calling filterResultsBasedOnSideViewController

Comment: @AntonijoDev thanks, tried that but not working. :(

Comment: did you trie puttin breakpoint in fetchedResultsController method? What happens when you step into it?

Comment: @AntonijoDev not sure what you mean. Ive logged the _fetchedController.fetchedObjects!.count and regardless my filtering is always the same.

Comment: `UITableView` `dataSource` is using `filteredObjects` or `NSFetchedResultsController` (`NSFRC`)? I don't see the code, but I assume `NSFRC` is used, because nothing happens. In your `filterResultsBasedOnSideViewController` do this: 1) Create or delete predicate and store / remove it in / from `filteredPredicate` property. 2) Trash old `self.fetchedResults...` by setting it to `nil`. 3) Call `self.tableView.reloadData()` And in your `fetchedResultsController` getter do this: 1) `fetchRequest.predicate = self.filteredPredicate`. If it's `nil`, no filtering otherwise yes.

Comment: @robertvojta a bit confused with what you 've suggested. Sorry. Yes I am using NSFRC. Step one got me confused. the other steps are easy to follow through but I m missing the first bit. Do i need to create separate NSFRC?

Comment: No, just trash the first one by setting it to nil. Then, when you call reloadData, fetchedResultsController is recreated again with or without predicate (depends if predicate is or isn't stored in property in your filterResults...).

Comment: @robertvojta sorry mate. it doesn't work. thanks

Comment: Then you did make another mistake elsewhere, but anyway, you've got it working, solved it yourself, which is always the best thing to do/learn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here is the code that works. Thanks everyone for their input that pointed me to the right way.

I created a `var filterIsOn  = false`
in my NSFRC I put an if statement:

```
  if filterIsOn  {

       //     print("is on")

            let filteredText: NSString = sprite
            filteredPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "keyWords contains[c] %@", filteredText)

            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sortID", ascending: true)
            fetchRequest.predicate = filteredPredicate
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        }
```

and changed the:

```
 let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil) //set cacheName to nil from "Master"
```

deleted the `func filterResultsBasedOnSideViewController() { }` and set the `filterIsOn = true` when I need to filter the results.

Simples! ;)